# How to add support for hex function to class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a class which implements the `__int__` method so that an instance can behave like an integer:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def __int__(self):
        return self._value
```

Using the `int` function on an instance works fine, and I thought other built-in functions were implicitly relying on it, for example `hex`. However, I get the following error message:

```
>>> x = MyClass(5)
>>> int(x)
5
>>> hex(x)
TypeError: 'MyClass' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I tried implementing the `__hex__` method in the same way as `__int__`, but this had no effect.

What do I have to do so that instances of my class are accepted by `hex`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As is specified in the documentation for [`hex(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#hex), you have to define the `__index__` method:

> **`hex(x)`**
>
> (..)
>
> If `x` is not a Python `int` object, it has to define an *`__index__()`* method that returns an *integer*.

(part omitted, formatted)

So for your case that is probably:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def __int__(self):
        return self._value

    def __index__(self):
        return self.__int__() #note you do not have to return the same as __int__
```

When running this in the console:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class MyClass:
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self._value = value
...     
...     def __int__(self):
...         return self._value
...     
...     def __index__(self):
...         return self.__int__()
... 
>>> foo=MyClass(14)
>>> hex(foo)
'0xe'
```

In case you want the "value" of `hex(..)` to be something else, you can thus define `__index__` different from `__int__` although I strongly advice against that. `hex(..)` furthermore guarantees that it will return a string (`str`) that is a correctly formatted hexadecimal number: you cannot return for instance a tuple, etc. Otherwise it will raise a `TypeError`. For instance:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __index__ returned non-int (type tuple)
```

if `__index__` returns a tuple.

Comment: In python2, implementing `__hex__` was indeed a possibility.